# Don't add command to MySQL CLI history

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

One can instruct Bash not to add a command to the CLI history by prepending the command with a space. How can one instruct the MySQL CLI interpreter to not add a command to the history? Prepending the command with a space does not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run mysql with the `-q` option to skip use of the history file.

Comment: Thank you Bill. This would require me to log out and log back in, though. However, if no other way is found then I'll accept this answer as it does provide a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, admittedly it does not let you suppress history on a statement-by-statement basis, like prepending a command with a space does in bash.

Comment: Thanks Bill. It does seem that there is no single-line 'don't remember this' option in the MySQL CLI interpreter.